# Getting error - Access is denied in OpenProcess() after enabling privileges

Tags: c++, security, winapi, elevated-privileges, openprocess

I want to get executable path of csrss process. I enabled privileges, but GetLastError() function returns error 5 in OpenProcess. I'm running Visual Studio as administrator and compiling program in 64bit mode, also I'm using Windows 8. Thanks to all.

```
HANDLE hcurrentProcess=GetCurrentProcess();
HANDLE hToken;
size_t error;

if (!OpenProcessToken(hcurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
return nullptr; 

if (CheckTokenPrivilege(hcurrentProcess, SE_DEBUG_NAME)) {  
LUID luid;

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid))
    return nullptr;

TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newState,prvsState;
DWORD length;
newState.PrivilegeCount = 1;
newState.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
newState.Privileges[0].Attributes = 2;

AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &newState, 28, &prvsState, &length);
error = GetLastError(); //error = 0

if (error == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
   return nullptr;
    //OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, 876);  also error 5
HANDLE  hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 876); 

    error = GetLastError(); }   //  error 5  Access is denied
```

Comment: That's pointless, use GetSystemDirectory() instead.

Comment: You will likely need to run as `System` in order to OpenProcess on csrss.exe

Comment: why that's pointless? I also want to get memory used by process, cpu time for process etc. I'll read about GetSystemDirectory().

Comment: You don't need `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` just to query process statistics. This is like asking for power of attorney so you can see what books they have overdue from the library.

Comment: A cool way of getting your windows directory is ((wchar_t*)0x7FFE0030), try it!

Comment: I also want to get modules and user name of processes

Comment: I just want to know why OpenProcess finishes with error though AdjustTokenPrivileges finish successfully

Comment: It's hard to help if we can't see what CheckTokenPrivilege is. Also, why are you getting the load driver privilege instead of the debug privilege?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to use SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME and forgot to correct it. In CheckTokenPrivilege I check is there SE_DEBUG_NAME in accesstoken to enable it

Comment: Maybe in Windows 8 it isn't working?

Comment: In windows 7 it works

Answer (score 0):

csrss.exe is a [Protected Processes Light](https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-1-pass-hash-mitigations-windows-81/) process, this protection was introduced in Windows 8.1.  You can no longer access it even with a low permission like PROCESS_VM_READ as a local System user, even with SeDebugPrivelage

Rather than what you're doing, just use [GetSystemDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemdirectorya) and then append "csrss.exe" on the end of it's result to get the path of the file.